# Prevent Derby SQL User Authentication Change

Tags: sql, authentication, sql-injection, derby

Can someone tell me if there exists SQL code for Derby to change a username or password of a database? How may I reproduce this to prevent it in future in my application?

What I'm busy doing, is to create a custom SQL query builder in my Java desktop application, but I want to prevent an end-user to accidentally or purposefully delete any table or database, change the username or password.

What SQL scripts can be run here which I may cancel out in my coding, and what basic things am I missing here?

All thoughts appreciated.

(This question has been asked on SE/Security to get different views. I want to get as much info on this as possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derby has an entire manual on security topics: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/security/

Perhaps you can start by studying that manual, and experimenting with the approaches it suggests, and then ask some more specific questions?